# jQuery add class with click not working. Is this a css or jquery error?

Tags: jquery, css

I think the error is in the logic. the animation works on when the CSS is set to change on hover, but when I try to add the click function then add the class, nothing happens. Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lelales/6qmsgcjn/7/

here is an example of the animation working on hover: https://www.studiocaillouette.com/menu-test-css/

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("#menu").click(function(){
  $(".cirlce").addClass("circle-grow");
```

```css
.circle,.content {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.circle {    
    background: rgba( 99, 99, 99, 0.8 );
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8 );
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    -o-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    transform: scale( 0.1 );
    
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
}

.circle-grow {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 );
    transform: scale( 1 );
    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
    opacity: .1;
}
.circle-grow .content {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script 
<div id="menu"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
<div class="circle">
    <span class="content"><a href="index.html">home</a><br />
          <a href="pricing.php">pricing</a><br />
          <a href="gallery.php">gallery</a><br />
          <a href="contact.php">contact</a><br />
         </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

typo error of the word 'cirlce' shoud change to 'circle':

```
$(".cirlce").addClass("circle-grow");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add JQUERY script in `head` tag:

   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. close functions with `});`
3. **You have typo mistake** use `circle` **and not** `$(".cirlce")`

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("#menu").click(function(){
  $(".circle").addClass("circle-grow");
});
});
```

```css
.circle,.content {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.circle {    
    background: rgba( 99, 99, 99, 0.8 );
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8 );
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    -o-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 0.1 );
    transform: scale( 0.1 );
    
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
}

.circle-grow {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 );
    transform: scale( 1 );
    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
    opacity: .1;
}
.circle-grow .content {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"><a href="#">menu</a></div>
<div class="circle">
    <span class="content"><a href="index.html">home</a><br />
          <a href="pricing.php">pricing</a><br />
          <a href="gallery.php">gallery</a><br />
          <a href="contact.php">contact</a><br />
         </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there was a typo error  for "circle"

Please check the following fiddle

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8Lb35cx/)

```
#circle {    
background: rgba( 99, 99, 99, 0.8 );
box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.8 );
border-radius: 100%;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
padding: 20px;
overflow: hidden;    
-webkit-transform: scale( 0.1 );
-moz-transform: scale( 01 );
-o-transform: scale( 0.1 );
-ms-transform: scale( 0.1 );
transform: scale( 0.1 );
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
line-height: 400px;
transition:ease all 1s
}
```